# How would I display the position of an element in an array?

Tags: java

My dilemma is after the user inputs a number, that number is then checked to see if it's in the array, if it is i'll let them know that is in the array along with the position of that said number.  I have it to where it prompts user for the number, but after that i get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int [] iGrades = new int [30];

      System.out.print ("Enter the grades, when you're done input (-1) ");
      for (int i=0; i<iGrades.length;i++)
      {
          iGrades [i]= kb.nextInt();
          if (iGrades [i]< 0)
          {
              break;
          }
      }
      System.out.print ("\nEnter a grade to check if it's in the array");
      iVal = kb.nextInt();
      for(int i=0; i<=iGrades.length; ++i)
       {
            if(iVal == (iGrades[i]))
            {
                found = true;
                for(int j=0; j<=iGrades.length; ++j)
                {
                    iGrades[j]=j+1;
                }
                break;
            }

       }

      if (found == true)
      {

         System.out.println(iVal + " is in the array at position ");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println(iVal + " is NOT in the array.");
      }
   }
```

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your second `for` loop. This

```
      for(int i=0; i<=iGrades.length; ++i)
```

Change the `<=` to `<`.

Comment: To print out the position of said integer, would i do something like this? iPos = iGrade[iVal]-iVal; then SOP (iVal + "position is " +iPos?

Comment: The position of the integer in the array is just `i`. What's SOP?

Comment: it's was System.out.print shortened.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says it already. You are checking an index that is not in the bounds of the array any more. Look at the second for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<=iGrades.length; ++i)
```

It runs from 0 to 30. The array only goes from 0 to 29 though. You have to use < instead here:

```
for(int i=0; i < iGrades.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays are zero-based, this

```
i<=iGrades.length
```

will allow `i` to equal `Grades.length`, which is one past the last index of the array. Use `<`.

Answer (score 0):

**Remember**

Array Index start from `0 to length of array -1`

Change the loop accordingly

**Hint** change `<=` to `<`